# awk, not clear about snippet in example from gnu-awk site

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm going through [this GNU awk example](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Split-Program.html#Split-Program). This program needs the [`ord()` and `chr()` library functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ordinal-Functions.html#Ordinal-Functions).

And that's where I get a little confused. I don't understand what does this code snippet does:

```
BEGIN    { _ord_init() }

function _ord_init(    low, high, i, t)
{
    low = sprintf("%c", 7) # BEL is ascii 7
    if (low == "\a") {    # regular ascii
        low = 0
        high = 127
    } else if (sprintf("%c", 128 + 7) == "\a") {
        # ascii, mark parity
        low = 128
        high = 255
    } else {        # ebcdic(!)
        low = 0
        high = 255
    }

    for (i = low; i <= high; i++) {
        t = sprintf("%c", i)
        _ord_[t] = i
    }
}
```

If you remove it (`BEGIN    { _ord_init() }`) and run the split.awk example, it works but in a strange way: there's a file called "xa?" that appear and the file "xab" is missing.

This is the input I have:

```
1 2 3 hello
1 3 4 world
2 4 5 india
4 2 1 china
```

I run the split program as such:

```
awk -f split.awk -2 input.txt
```

And the content of split.awk is as such: well its the code in the two preivous urls put into one file "split.awk".

So again, what does the function `_ord_init` do exactly?

Comment: The function is performing work that was important to the world in 1987.

Comment: It is initializing the `_ord_` mapping. Without it the mapping has no values and you get `xa<1>`.

Comment: Is the `?` in the filename a regular `?` or a unknown-character sign (often a question mark in a black diamond shape)? It looks to me as though the filename should end up containing a null byte.

Comment: I wonder what's the name of that minicomputer manufacturer that used ASCII, with mark parity, and why they did that...

Answer (score 0):

It define the character set to use at runtime.

It uses a local response to a specific request ( `sprintf("%c", 7)` and `sprintf("%c", 128 + 7) == "\a"`) to allow `chr()` and `ord()` to answer in the same character set.

3 main family set are treated (other are untreated here)
 - ascii (most used at development time of awk)
 - parity ascii (ASCII but with the 8th bit is always set to 1 instead of 0 or parity breaker in transmission [to insure there is always an odd number of 1])
 - ebcdic (typically mainframe)